# Doesn't show pizzas' names on pizzas.html under many-to-one relationship [Python Crash Course exercises 18-8]

Tags: django, python-3.x

I wanted to follow the methodology in Python Crash Course Ch. 18 on building the `learning_logs` app to build the `pizzas` app. However I'm stuck at displaying the pizzas' name in `pizzas.html`.

There should be 2 pizzas, named "Hawaiian" and "Meat Lovers". I added both using the admin account. Checked through the shell that both are stored in `Pizza.objects.all()` so I guess it's the problem to recall them.

---

Some codes for you all's reference:

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Pizza

# Create your views here.

def index(request):

    """ The home page for Pizzeria. """

    return render(request, "pizzas/index.html")

def pizzas(request):

    """ Show all pizzas available. """

    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
    content = {"pizza": pizzas}
    return render(request, "pizzas/pizzas.html", content)
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Pizza(models.Model):

    """ Pizza available. """
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):

        """ Return a string representation of the pizza name. """
        return self.name

class Topping(models.Model):

    """ The toppoings on the pizza. """

    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):

        """ Return a string representation of the toppings. """
        return self.text
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = "pizzas"

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),

    # Show all pizzas.
    path("pizzas/", views.pizzas, name = "pizzas"),
]
```

pizzas.html:

```html
{% extends 'pizzas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Pizzas</p>
    <ul>
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
            <li>{{ pizza }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No pizza duh.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

---

Expected to see both "Hawaiian" and "Meat Lovers" appears in the list under "Pizzas" in localhost:8000/pizzas.html but instead shows "no pizza duh". What do I miss?

I did see changing the relationship to both models would help solve the problem but if I don't, how can I change the other parts to get what I expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have anything called `pizzas` in your template context; you named the variable `pizza`.

You should change the context to use `pizzas`:

```
content = {"pizzas": pizzas}
```

Comment: So when I call for ```pizzas``` in the HTML file I am asking the value from the key of the same name in the ```content``` dictionary?

Comment: Hell yeah it is. Thanks a lot.